# How do I animate an array made from a class in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

So I am new to using three.js and at the moment I am just messing around with a few basic ideas. I have created a class for making cubes appear in random places and an array of cubes that gets filled by a for loop. I am trying to animate the cubes so that they all fall slowly at the same time. The problem is I cant seem to get them to all animate, only the last cube placed into the array. Here is my code:

```
class Boxes {

  constructor() {

      this.boxGeo = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,1,1);
      this.boxMat = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    color: 0x673612
});
    this.box = new THREE.Mesh(this.boxGeo, this.boxMat);
    this.box.position.x = Math.random() * (10 - -10) + -10;
    this.box.position.y = Math.random() * (6 - -6) + -6;
    this.box.position.z = Math.random() * (6 - -6) + -6;

    scene.add(this.box);


  }
  update() {


  }

}

var randBoxes = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 22; i++) {
  var newBox = new Boxes();
  randBoxes.push(newBox);

};

fall_speed = 0.01;
var animate = function() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  newBox.box.position.y = newBox.box.position.y - fall_speed; 

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};


animate();
```

any help would be great! thank you

Comment: You are updating just the last box, newBox is reference to the last object . Loop randBoxes and update position of each box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're pushing all your box objects to an array, you'll have to loop through it again for the animation:

```
for (i = 0; i < randBoxes.length; i++) {
    randBoxes[i].box.position.y = newBox.box.position.y - fall_speed;
}
```

The reason your current code is only animating the last `newBox` object is because, in your first `for` loop, it left off as defining the variable `newBox` as the 22nd box in your array, since that's where the loop stopped.

Comment: `randBoxes[i].box.position.y = newBox.box.position.y - fall_speed;` should be `randBoxes[i].box.position.y -=  fall_speed;`, otherwise all the cubes will have the same `y`-coordinate based on the position of the `newBox.box`.